# SQL Server Conditional Unique Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database, unique-constraint

Given the following table (and sample data):

```
PK | ClientID | SetID | Title
-----------------------------
P1 | C1       | S1    | Title1
P2 | C1       | S1    | Title1
P3 | C2       | S2    | Title1
P4 | C2       | S2    | Title1
P3 | C1       | S3    | Title2
P5 | C1       | S3    | Title2
```

Assuming a `Set` belongs to a `Client`, can I have a unique index that constraints the title being unique within a client except with it's siblings within the same set.

So for example, I can have `Title1` in two `Clients` but not twice in one `Client`. Now for `Client1`, I want to have a second record with `Title1` but only when it has the same `SetID` as all others with `Title`.

Just to note, I'm using SQL Azure, but I'm interested more generally (e.g 2008 R2/2012) too.

**Edit:**
Please note that I cannot change the structure of the table. It exists this way already, and has a complex business layer behind it. If I can fix this, as is, then great, if not, then I can leave it broken.

Comment: I can not see how you are going to have unique index of three columns that allows to have duplicated information. I suppose this could be fix only if you add for example identity column in order to be part of the index, but you are not allowed to change the table.

Comment: I can add a column, but cannot make intrusive changes such as splitting the table into two.

Comment: @gotqn. It doesn't have to be a unique index, that's just what I'm thinking would do the trick, just haven't figured out how! :)

Comment: No, you won't be able to create a unique index in that scenario because the rules allow duplicates.  You will need to enforce that in a trigger or in the data layer of your app(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try additional indexed view.

For example, a table:

```
create table dbo.Test (PK int, ClientID int, SetID int, Title varchar(50), primary key (PK))

insert into dbo.Test values
    (1, 1, 1, 'Title1')
    ,(2, 1, 1, 'Title1')
    ,(3, 2, 2, 'Title1')
    ,(4, 2, 2, 'Title1')
    ,(5, 1, 3, 'Title2')
    ,(6, 1, 3, 'Title2')
```

The view and index:

```
create view dbo.vTest
with schemabinding
as
    select ClientID, Title, SetID, cnt=count_big(*)
    from dbo.Test
    group by ClientID, Title, SetID
GO
create unique clustered index UX_vTest on dbo.vTest (ClientID, Title)
GO
```

Then:

```
insert into dbo.Test values (7, 1, 1, 'Title1') -- will pass
insert into dbo.Test values (8, 1, 1, 'Title1') -- will pass
insert into dbo.Test values (9, 1, 2, 'Title1') -- will fail
insert into dbo.Test values (10, 2, 2, 'Title1') -- will pass
insert into dbo.Test values (11, 1, 3, 'Title1') -- will fail
```

Comment: This is the route I'm most considering. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If I got the question right I would add another table to link between `SetID` and `Title` which have a `1:1` relation and add a unique index on `ClientID and SetID`

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [Index_Name]
ON [dbo].[MyTable]([ClientID ], [SetID])
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I agree that would be a better set up but unfortunately I don't have the option to change the structure. My options are: add columns (computed?), add indexes, views, etc.

Answer (score 0):

how about adding an on insert/update trigger that performs the checks and raises a fail exception if the rule violated.
you could add these without changing the data model.

Comment: I have considered this but it feels a bit dirty. I'm using an AFTER INSERT DML trigger for a purpose that really needed a BEFORE INSERT. My concern with using a trigger to do this is performance. Can you provide pros and cons?

Comment: If you can use a trigger you can create `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger to handle the insert and make the check.

Comment: @gotgn. Thanks, I'm aware of that, but an INSTEAD OF trigger requires that I rewrite the insert that would've happened. I'd be happy with that if I were able to do `INSERT INTO [table] SELECT * FROM INSERTED` but I can't do that with identities.